# I'm working on some practice dataset in python

Tags: python, pandas

What does this line of code mean?

```
train_data.isnull().any()
```

I don't get it

Comment: I don't know much pandas, but I would hazard a guess that it checks whether any of the values in the dataframe are null.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a df called `train_data` like this:

```
train_data = pd.DataFrame( {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[2,3,4]})
```

`train_data.isnull().any()` tells you if in any column there is a `nan` element:

```
a    False
b    False
dtype: bool
```

for this df: `train_data = pd.DataFrame( {'a':[np.nan,2,3], 'b':[2,3,4]})`
you will have:

```
a     True
b    False
dtype: bool
```

`any()` is used to know if any of element of the column is `np.nan`. For this df:

```
train_data = pd.DataFrame( {'a':[np.nan,5,np.nan], 'b':[2,3,4]})
```

`train_data.isnull()` will have as output the boolean for each element:

```
       a      b
0   True  False
1  False  False
2   True  False
```

Answer (score 1):

The `isnull` returns a boolean statement for each value, the any goes to each columns to check if any trues, then go further with any, another any t will check is there any trues or not

if you don't know, `isnull` checks for numpy nan for each value

In the other hand `any` can have an `axis` argument, if it's 1 it means for each row, otherwise no.

Example (also please read the comments):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[np.nan,2,3], 'b':[2,np.nan,4]})
>>> df.isnull() # for each value
       a      b
0   True  False
1  False   True
2  False  False
>>> df.isnull().any() # for each column
a    True
b    True
dtype: bool
>>> df.isnull().any(axis=1) # for each row
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
>>> df.isnull().any().any() # for any value 
True
```